# Cómo encontrar el mayor elemento de cada fila y el menor de cada columna

Tags: c++

Encontrar el mayor elemento de cada fila y el menor de cada columna

Con una matriz aleatoria en c++;

```
int matriz [12][12]; 
int min=0;
//valor minimo 
int max=0;
//valor maximo 
for (int fila =0; fila < 12; fila++) { 
    for (int columna = 0; columna < 12;columna++) { 
        int valor = matriz[fila][columna]= 2 * ((rand() % 256) + 1);
        std::cout <<matriz [fila][columna] << " "; 
        if(valor<min){ 
            min=valor; 
        } 
        if(valor>max){ 
            max=valor; 
        } 
    } 
    std::cout<<std::endl; 
} 
std::cout<< "***********************************;
```

El profe pide resultado de cada columna y cada fila que aparezca en la matriz

Comment: Seria ideal que coloques un ejemplo de lo que has intentado

Comment: int matriz [12][12];
    int min=0;//valor minimo
    int max=0;//valor maximo

    for (int fila =0; fila < 12; fila++)
    {
        for (int columna = 0; columna < 12;columna++)
        {
            int valor = matriz[fila][columna]= 2 * ((rand() % 256) + 1);

            cout <<matriz [fila][columna] << " ";

            if(valor<min){
                min=valor;
            }
            if(valor>max){
                max=valor;
            }
        }
       cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<< "***********************************

Comment: Pero el profe pide resultado de cada columna y cada fila que aparezca en la matriz

Comment: Tus comentarios en realidad deben ser ediciones a tu pregunta. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: El código obtiene el máximo y el mínimo de toda la matriz. También es recomendable que hagas el llenado de la matriz por separado de otras operaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Estás llenando la matriz con valores pares en el rango 2-512, así que bastaría con que inicialices `max` a un valor menor a 2 y `min` a un valor mayor que 512.

Por otro lado en un caso más general para que el cálculo de mínimo y máximo (con tipo de dato `int`) funcione correctamente debes inicializar los valores `min` y `max` a los valores máximo y mínimo absolutos respectivamente. Puedes usar las definiciones `INT_MAX` e `INT_MIN` para ello.

```
#include <climits>

int min=INT_MAX;
//valor minimo 
int max=INT_MIN;
//valor maximo
```